# Where to find schedule for bus from Peniche to Baleal

Tags: buses, portugal

I stay in Baleal, Portugal and sometimes I want to visit nearest city Peniche. I saw several times bus in that direction but I didn't manage to find the schedule. When I asked at the surf school reception they said that bus operates randomly. Sure I trust them but maybe there is a schedule exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Rodoviária do Tejo" company has buses for this travel. Here you can find the schedule: http://www.rodotejo.pt/horarios/todosresultados/0415/1246/1/0 and here http://www.rodotejo.pt/horarios/todosresultados/1246/0415/1 for the return.

There is no english version but I hope you can still gather the information you need. They also have a number to call (707 200 334), you can also try to talk with them.

Also, if I can help you further, please leave a comment, I/we'll do my/our best to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The buses in Portugal has not schedule time. Sometimes at bus stop you can see a schedule like this:

- 10am - 1am:  **30min**
- 1pm  - 4pm:  **15min**
- 4am  - 22pm: **30min**

It means the interval between buses. From 1pm to 4pm the buses came with 15 minutes of interval. This is not randomly, but they don't have a specific time.